# Protected left turn to the right lane to enter a gas station on the immediate corner?

Tags: united-states, traffic

In Washington State and most states that I'm aware of the law on turning left into a road with 2 lanes of travel to the left stipulate that the driver should make the turn into the leftmost "practicable" lane.

RCW 46.61.290:

> (2) Left turns. The driver of a vehicle intending to turn left shall approach the turn in the extreme left-hand lane lawfully available to traffic moving in the direction of travel of the vehicle. Whenever practicable the left turn shall be made to the left of the center of the intersection and so as to leave the intersection or other location in the extreme left-hand lane lawfully available to traffic moving in the same direction as the vehicle on the roadway being entered.

Or in New York State:

> (c) Left turns on other than two-way roadways. At any intersection
> where traffic is restricted to one direction on one or more of the
> roadways, the driver of a vehicle intending to turn left at any such
> intersection shall approach the intersection in the extreme left-hand
> lane of the roadway lawfully available to traffic moving in the
> direction of travel of such vehicle or, where travel on the shoulder or
> slope has been authorized, from the shoulder or slope, and after
> entering the intersection the left turn shall be made so as to leave the
> intersection, as nearly as practicable, in the left-hand lane lawfully
> available to traffic moving in such direction upon the roadway being
> entered.

Since the lawmakers did not use specific language that one "must always" turn into the leftmost lane that means that there are situations where one is allowed to turn into other lanes of travel, where that is not "practicable".

How broadly is that term interpreted?

Most of the discussion that I can find online relates to avoiding hazards like contruction or parked/stalled vehicles.  What about if your destination is ultimately a business or residence which is on the corner such that you cannot enter the leftmost lane and practically change lanes in order to enter the business?

And consider the case where the left turner has a protected green arrow, their destination is that corner gas station (or whatever) and there is a right-turn-on red driver in the initial opposing lane to create a lane conflict, and then there's a collision.  The driver turning left on the protected arrow clearly states that they were heading for the gas station and there's camera evidence which backs that up as best as possible before the collision.

Comment: It doesn't appear relevant at all that the driver is trying to enter the gas station. The fact that it's too difficult to enter the station without creating a conflict or a danger means **they should *not try* to enter the station that way!** You always have the option of approaching it from a different direction; make a U-turn or some other direction-changing manoeuvre further up.

Comment: Concerning the last case, a driver turning right on red is supposed to yield to all traffic already in the intersection, and so would be at fault.  See, for example, RCW 46.61.055 3(a):  "Vehicle operators planning to make such turns shall remain stopped to allow other vehicles **lawfully within or approaching the intersection** control area to complete their movements."